# How to test an infinite, recursive Task in Elixir

Tags: testing, elixir, erlang-otp

Please check this code:

```
defmodule InfinitePollTask do
  def poll(opts \\ [])
    # function body code here
    poll(new_opts)
  end
end
```

I want to write a unit test for the function body code, assuming the function body perform some important computation using `opts` and produce a `new_opts` for the next iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd just pull the computation out into a separate function that returns new_opts, and test that:

```
defmodule InfinitePollTask do
  def poll(opts \\ [])
    poll(do_poll(opts))
  end

  def do_poll(opts)
    # important computation
  end
end

defmodule InfinitePollTaskTest do
  use ExUnit.Case

  test "some case" do
    assert InfinitePollTask.do_poll(some_opts) == some_result_opts
  end
end
```